# Unable to load multiple textures in opengl es 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

I'm attempting to load two textures and pass them on to two samplers in my shader, however both the samplers return the first texture I load. Furthermore if I don't load a texture into GL_TEXTURE0, both the samplers return black. I've reduced it to a single sampler/texture and still have the same issue:

```
    GLuint texture1;

    glGenTextures(2, &texture1);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); //if this is GL_TEXTURE1 or any other, I get black
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    [self LoadTextureData: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"normals" ofType:@"png"]];

    glUniform1i(uniforms[SAMPLER_1], 1); //whether this is 0 or 1 or anything else doesn't seem to make any difference for both samplers. 

    return TRUE;
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
I'm reasonably sure my sampler indices are correct, as is my shader. LoadTextureData boils down to a glTexImage2D.

Edit:
This is how I attempt to load and set the two textures

```
        //texture 1
    GLuint texture1;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    [self LoadTextureData: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"normals" ofType:@"png"]];

    //texture 2
    GLuint texture2;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    [self LoadTextureData: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bricks" ofType:@"jpg"]];


    glUniform1i(uniforms[SAMPLER_1], 0);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[SAMPLER_2], 1);
```

The result is both samplers return the 'normals' image.

LoadTextureData, assignment of sampler IDs, and my shader can be found at http://paste2.org/p/1514200

Comment: Have you loaded the first one with glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); and the second with glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);?

Comment: Yes, however I'm not sure if I'm going it correctly. I'm appending my post to include how I load both.

Comment: One thing that has bitten me is that JPEG images are strictly 3 channel (no alpha channel) while PNG images can contain an alpha channel. Double check LoadTextureData to verify that loading the JPEG isn't generating any OpenGL errors.

Comment: Tanks for pointing that out, I didn't realize it would fail silently. However my loading creates 32 bit textures and I double checked by attempting to load two PNGs to the same result.

Comment: Ok this is a bit embarassing. I discovered that I was loading the textures before the shader, and subsequently my sampler IDs were incorrect even though they looked correct because I only checked after all loading finished. Should I delete this question, or what's the procedure for questions that no one else will benefit from?

Comment: @Bicubic the benifit of this is to tell others to make sure that they load their shaders before trying to assign textures to the samplers in them. I suggest you write this up into an answer that someone else might find useful one day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long of the short of it: make sure you assign textures to samplers -after- the shader is loaded. I was tricked into thinking uniforms[] is assigned correctly because I was only checking it after all loading had completed.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but don't have a problem with the order. What exactly is your uniforms array and SAMPLER_1 and SAMPLER_2 here?

Answer (score 3):

```
GLuint texture1;
glGenTextures(2, &texture1);
```

You generate two textures, but alloc variable only for one.

Try this:

```
GLuint textures[2];
glGenTextures(2, textures);
```

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me and I spent 2 or 3 hours trying to figure it out.  Your answer was right for you but this was what I was doing...

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureInfo[textureIndex].texture);
glUniform1i(glPrograms[currentProgram].glUniforms[U_textureSampler], 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureInfo[textureIndex].texture);
glUniform1i(glPrograms[currentProgram].glUniforms[U_secondTextureSampler], 0);
```

My entire 3 hours of debugging, testing things, cursing, trying to figure out why BOTH textures were the same thing... was because of the 0 instead of a 1 on the 2nd one.

It should have been:

```
glUniform1i(glPrograms[currentProgram].glUniforms[U_secondTextureSampler], 1);
```

It's not just the GL_TEXTURE0 and GL_TEXTURE1 that makes it the 2nd texture. It's that 1 there too.

Hope it saves someone else a couple of hours.